# Set up Box2D and Cocos2D in xcode 4

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I updated to Xcode 4 with the release this week. I also updated to the latest Cocos2d distribution (1.0.0-beta). I deleted the old Cocos2d folder and replaced it with the new one (same for box2d), but now nothing works!!! I have been using many hours to try and figure it out.

What settings do you have to set to make it work?

Best regards
Kristian

Answer (score 1):

I was recently in your situation when I updated to Xcode4. Basically my box2d application was getting alot of compile errors.
After smashing my head against my desk for a day, I decided to remake my project and import my methods etc into the cocos2d helloworldlayer template.
Nothing else really worked for me.

I also updated to the latest bleeding edge version of Cocos2d to ensure that it was supported by Xcode4.

Comment: I actually fixed it :)

i did the same thing as you :D